# Does proxyfying through mod_rewrite slows down retrieving the content?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using [mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html) to load images from another domain. I'm using the P flag to hide that the images are coming from another domain. Im however wondering whether this slows down the process of retrieving the image. The manual isn't very clear how it actually works. Does it internally just redirects the request or does it retrieve the content by itself and forwards it to the user (which causes the IP packets to be transferred two times)?

Comment: Is there any way you can fire up Wireshark and then visit your site? That's one surefire way to see if your server is retrieving the images and then sending them to you (like a proxy) or if it's just giving your client the URLs and making the client retrieve them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy module makes an additional internal request to the backend ressource. So you end up with two chained http requests to be processed (by a single or two servers, depends on your setup). In case both urls are located on the same system then it is not a tcp connection, but still a separated request which has to be processed.

So the answer is "yes": the retrieval of images is slowed down.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I'll remove it. Having two http requests for every image is a huge overhead. They should mention it in the manual.